The high-frequency requests from Dapr are causing errors in Zipkin
I am testing the performance of the Dapr state store, using the state store operations provided in the Dapr dotnet-sdk. I enabled 10 threads simultaneously, each performing 1000 write operations, with each write operation being 10kb in size, and it worked fine. However, when I increased the number of threads to 20, the terminal displayed the following error(Zipkin is running on port 9411.):
ℹ️  Checking if Dapr sidecar is listening on GRPC port 45823
ℹ️  Dapr sidecar is up and running.
ℹ️  Updating metadata for appPID: 185478
ℹ️  Updating metadata for app command: dotnet run dapr 20 1000
✅  You're up and running! Both Dapr and your app logs will appear here.

2024/04/11 20:16:16 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:16 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": write tcp 127.0.0.1:46198->127.0.0.1:9411: use of closed network connection
2024/04/11 20:16:16 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:16 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:16 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:16 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:16 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:17 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:17 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9411: connect: connection refused
2024/04/11 20:16:17 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9411: connect: connection refused
2024/04/11 20:16:17 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9411: connect: connection refused
2024/04/11 20:16:17 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:17 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:17 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:17 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:17 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:17 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:18 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:18 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:18 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:18 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:18 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:18 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:18 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:18 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:19 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:19 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF
2024/04/11 20:16:19 request to http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans failed: Post "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans": EOF

I'd like to know what's causing the issue and how to fix or prevent it.

Is Zipkin still running or did it crash? Did it start throttling requests because it can't keep up? Running both your services and your monitoring system on the same machine means they compete for the same resources.

BTW Dapr is using OpenTelemetry now which has become the standard for distributed tracing. No matter the wire protocol though, the way to scale is to batch spans or sample them based on various strategies. Instead of hundreds of microservices hitting Zipkin you can have one or more OTEL collectors that collect, batch, sample and forward traces and metrics to the monitoring systems

@PanagiotisKanavos Zipkin remains running, but encounters errors only during a short period of performance testing. Zipkin's log shows 'Terminating due to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space'.

@PanagiotisKanavos I'll delve deeper into the solution you mentioned, thank you!

"Terminating due to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" is a pretty strong sign that zipkin did not, in fact, remain running.
